# Override entire user login / register page

Tags: users, theming

I am trying to figure out a way to override the entire `/user` page in **D7**.
There is a lot of articles out there that goes about altering the form, but I want to be able to rework the entire page (forms included) to get them into a nice bootstrap layout.

A lot of the information on the web is talking about `page--user--login.tpl.php`, but this does not work at all.

When using `page--user.tpl.php`, it seems to render my template file, but I cannot re-render the form.

When using

```
<?php
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_login');
  print drupal_render($form);
?>
My HTML goes here
<?php
  // Render any remaining elements, such as hidden inputs (token, form_id, etc).
  print drupal_render_children($form);
?>
```

I keep getting an infinite redirect loop. My best guess is because of a problem with the form_id that does not match.

Ps: I am using a bootstrap subtheme.

All information about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy your theme's `page.tpl.php` to `page--user.tpl.php` as you already have to create the template that will be used for the page.

Following that, in your `template.php` create implement [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) using either `user_login` or `user_register` as the form ID depending on which part of the page you're wishing to alter. If you either add a `dpm()` or an xdebug breakpoint in here and refresh the page, you should see the form structure and the available fields. in this field, you can then alter the form elements' `#attributes`, `#prefix`, and `#suffix` fields to add the required Bootstrap classes.

I.e. (not a user register field, just an example)

```
$form['my_element'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('My textfield'),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="form-group">,
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => [
      'form-control',
    ]
  ],
]
```

One last thing that might be helpful; there was a change in Drupal 7.33 (I think) that added a `theme_debug` value to the global `$conf`. If you add `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` to your `settings.php`, then any template the is used will be shown in the dev tools as a comment just before it is loaded - this makes is super easy to work out which template is being called, as well as listing any possible alternatives.

Comment: Thanks you very much Chapabu! I totally missed the point of page.tpl.php. I was overly focussed on finding a user-login.tpl.php file or something like this. The form_alter() solution, i am well aware of. I have marked you anwser over the other one below because the page.tpl.php was actually the point i was missing!

Answer (score 1):

In template.php, you could add an alter form to add classes, a wrapper, and I think also be able to add/edit fields in the form. Would that be of any help?

Example:

```
function THEME_NAME_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'custom-class';
}
```

in template.php would add the class `custom-class` around the login form, which you can then use to style the form.

As for using templates, I think they might have to be added in the correct location as well, e.g. I have recently built a site using custom templates with the user pages templates in `/sites/all/theme-name/templates/user/`. This also allows you to use custom markup. For example:

```
<div class="custom-class--wrapper">
    <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
</div>
```

which is used in the file `user-register-form.tpl.php`.

Also, have you considered using panelizer to customise pages, that would be a lot easier than using template.php or custom templates. And if a change doesn't seem to take effect, you should try and clear the drupal cache.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; to write a good answer you should describe how the asker can actually go about performing the task they've required, not make an exceptionally broad statement.

Comment: @Chapabu Sorry about that. Hopefully this is better